# Need help implementing a command line ";" option into C-Shell Script

Tags: c, shell

I'm currently working on writing a shell program in C. I have most of the basics down, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the ";" to work properly, that is, to make it so when I type something like "command1 ; command2" when the shell is running, it executes the first command AND THEN the second command. Right now, it basically has the same functionality as the "|" command. Here is the code for my ";" command section:

```
char* cmd = line;
            char* also = strchr(cmd, ';'); /* Finds first ';'*/
            char* next = strchr(cmd, '|'); /* Find first '|' */

            while (also != NULL){
                    /* 'also' points to ';' */
                    *also = '\0';
                    input = go(cmd, input, first, 0);

                    cmd = also + 1;
                    also = strchr(cmd, ';'); /* Find next ';' */
                    first = 0;
            }
```

`

Anyone have any tips on how I can get this working properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that when you input `command1 ; command2` you'll go execute `command1`, but since you're looking for another `;` `command2` will never be executed, since also will be set at `null`. An input with `command1 ; command2 ;` will be executed though.

What you want to do is looking up for either a `;` or a `'\n'` if thats from the standard input, or `\n` or `#EOF` if you're reading from a file. So you need to make changes at this very line :

```
also = strchr(cmd, ';');
```

Good luck.